# Selenium Webdriver (Python) - Click on a div element (checkbox)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to click on a non-button element (checkbox) inside an iframe but am not able to click on it using the selenium webdriver. The URL is https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service and the box that I want to click is shown in the screenshot below:

NOTE: Select the following options to reach the screen shown in the screenshot below: Click on New Customer "MAKE. MODEL. YEAR". Select Make as "NISSAN" -> Year as "2018" -> Model as "ALTIMA" -> Trim as "SL" -> Engine Type as "I4" -> Enter Mileage as "35000" -> Click on "CONTINUE" at the bottom. On the following page, the goal is to click on the checkbox Maintenance Package Standard / Schedule 1 (the checkbox needs to be clicked but I am not able to find the correct code line for Selenium to be able to click on it)

Below is the working Selenium Python script that I wrote to successfully navigate until the page that shows the checkbox that I wish to click:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\gh456\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# first frame - by css selector
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[src^="https://consumer.xtime.com"]')))

# second frame - by ID
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('xt01'))

driver.find_element_by_id("new_customer_button").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("NISSAN").click()

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "2018"))).click()

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ALTIMA"))).click()

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "SL"))).click()

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "I4"))).click()

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "mileage_input"))).send_keys("35000")

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "continue_button"))).click()

# Click on the checkbox 
# ---??????????????????
```

Can someone help me with the correct code to make selenium webdriver to click that checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is covered by another element...

Also, I changed the `expected_conditions` as `element_to_be_clickable()`.

So you can use [`ActionChains`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\gh456\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# first frame - by css selector
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[src^="https://consumer.xtime.com"]')))

# second frame - by ID
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('xt01'))

driver.find_element_by_id("new_customer_button").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("NISSAN").click()

wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "2018"))).click()

wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ALTIMA"))).click()

wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "SL"))).click()

wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "I4"))).click()

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "mileage_input"))).send_keys("35000")

wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "continue_button"))).click()

check_box_el = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="maintenance_package_section"]//label[@class="checkbox"]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(check_box_el).click().perform()
```

Screenshot:
[image]

You might want to use `CSS_SELECTOR` and not XPATH:

```
check_box_el = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#maintenance_package_section > div label')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(check_box_el).click().perform()
```

Comment: Hi Moshe! Your code gives me an error. Please click on https://ibb.co/f9bvc03 to see the screenshot of the error. Please help me how can I fix this. Thanks!

Comment: @SiddharthGosalia I don't see this error by me... what line of code generates this error?

Comment: The last line of the code beginning with ActionChains is throwing the error. See more details here: https://ibb.co/34cgS6k.

Comment: @SiddharthGosalia did you import it? `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`

Comment: The error is on an `iframe`... the element we are clicking `check_box_el` is not an `iframe`... so I don't know what is the issue... be me it works fine!

Comment: I figured out the reason for the error. The button to be clicked was not visible within the browser window on my laptop. So I just had to add an extra line of code along with your code which would scroll to the top of the page before clicking on the element: `check_box_el = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#maintenance_package_section > div label')))
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
time.sleep(1)

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(check_box_el).click().perform()`

Comment: @SiddharthGosalia glad to hear it worked out... I use a big screen for testing...

Answer (score 1):

Try this locator `(//*[@class="checkbox"])[1]` and use `ActionChains`.

```
chk = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="checkbox"])[1]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(chk).click().perform()
```

You can change `[1]` to `[2]` or `[3]` if you want

Comment: Hi Frian! Your code gives me the same error as Moshe's code. Please click on https://ibb.co/f9bvc03 to see the screenshot of the error. Please help me how can I fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your check box is not enabled. Please, have some conditions following is_selected()...And check whether it is enabled now.....
http://selenium-interview-questions.blogspot.com/2014/03/working-with-checkboxes-in-selenium.html